# asciidoctor: how to provide source-highlighter JavaScript File offline

Tags: asciidoctor

I use Asciidoctor for our User Guide. A requirement is that there is no access to the internet for the users.

I use prettify:

`:source-highlighter: prettify`

This creates in the `HTML`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.min.js"></script>
<script>prettyPrint()</script>
```

What I need is something, like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/prettify.min.css">
<script src="assets/js/prettify.min.js"></script>
<script>prettyPrint()</script>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking [at the source](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/blob/master/lib/asciidoctor/syntax_highlighter/prettify.rb) you can specify

```
:prettifydir: assets
```

to receive an HTML output of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/prettify.min.css">
<script src="assets/run_prettify.min.js"></script>
```

To make it work for your users, you'll need to put the referenced files at the location yourself; Asciidoctor won't do that for you AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Use [asciidoctor-rouge](https://github.com/jirutka/asciidoctor-rouge) or [asciidoctor-highlight.js](https://github.com/jirutka/asciidoctor-highlight.js).

Comment: thanks for the proposal -  I don't want to change it just fix it;)